# How can people use my own created IOS app? I have no paid account in apple

Tags: ios, iphone

I have created a simple IOS app with Swift. Do i need any paid apple id for using the app into my friend's iPhone? Is there any free way to use the app?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any free way to use the app?

No. Your paid Apple Developer membership is your ticket to distribution of your app. Distribution to others is impossible without it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any free way to use the app?

The only way is to run the app directly to your friends iOS devices connected with xCode. To do this you need a free Apple Developer account.

But for distribution and beta distribution you need a paid developer account.